# Values differ at index 1 - for equal nested arrays

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Why it's not equal? It's the same with CollectionAssert too.

```
        var a = new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 } };
        var b = new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 } };
        // if you comment these two lines the test passes
        a[0] = a[1];
        b[0] = b[1];
        Assert.That(a, Is.EqualTo(b));
```

Gives:

```
Expected and actual are both <System.Int32[2][]>
Values differ at index [1]
  Expected and actual are both <System.Int32[2]>
```

I'm using nunit 2.6.4.14350 and run from ReSharper test runner in VS .NET 4.5 project.

The same is reproducable for standalone NUnit test runner (2.6.4).

Comment: when I run this, it is green.

Comment: @Stephan added env details

Comment: @HimBromBeere there are two elements {1,2} and {3,4}

Comment: @HimBromBeere look again ;-)

Comment: Making a simple console application, `a.Equals(b)` is always `false` (expected, see @HimBromBeere answer).

Comment: @Vlad with same Env as you describe that test passes for me. [See Image](http://pasteboard.co/ZaFEGYd.png)

Comment: @tchelidze I just tried it in a new project and it passes there. Very strange...

Comment: @tchelidze I referenced the same nunit version and now it's reproducing

Comment: @Vlad can you [disasseble](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) `NUnit` `dll` and compare two implementation, just for interest.

Comment: @tchelidze I installed NUnit 2.6.4 from nuget and it gives the exception. But NUnit 3 doesn't.

Comment: @tchelidze I created an issue https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1209

Comment: @Vlad , nice question! my answer in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33189992/4332059) might be the solution.(the answer is for `MsTest`, but it should work for `NUnit` as well...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this bug but it's closed as won't fix: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1209

So you can either use NUnit 3.x or accept that it's just broken in NUnit 2.6.x.

Answer (score -1):

Althoug either `a` and `b`are of type `Int32[2][]` that does not mean they are equal as `Equals` returns true if the *references* of your arrays are identical which they are not. What you want is to echeck if their content is the same using `a.SequenceEquals(b)`.

Comment: But why then it passes when I comment those two lines?